# Use ts-node (or similar) to import both npm packages exported using ESM and CommonJS, using esm import

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules, ts-node, node-tsx

I would like a setup for my project with the following configurations.

1. I would like to use typescript in my source code.
2. I would like to use ESM only in my source code, ie. `import foo from 'bar'`.
3. I do not want dist files outside npm_modules when executing my index.ts file.
4. I would like to be able to load files exported with `module.exports = ...`
5. I would like to be able to load files exported with `export default { foo: ... }`
6. I don't want to use .mjs extensions.

Many of these features works out of the box with frameworks like `next.js`, `vite.js`, `cra`. However these all have alot of additional functionaliy and restrictions i do not want. For example a dev server which I do not need, and restrictions to where the `src` folder must be.

In short, I just want to execute self written typescript ESM files, using all sorts of 3rd party imports.

What is the best approach? Find and existing framework, like ts-node? Or setup something from scratch?

Any input on how to set this up, or which frameworks to check out is much appreciated.

What I am currently trying is ts-node, but i can't get ESM imports to work. I get a message saying i should set ´type´ to `module` in my package.json. But in my experiance this will prohibit loading of 3rd party code using CommonJS export.

Is it possible to set a specific loader for ts-node?

Comment: If you want an esm-first project with .js extensions then you need to set type: module. ESM modules can consume CJS just fine.

Comment: Becouse some packages from the npm registry still use CommonJS exports.

Comment: But as Dimava commented, [tsx](https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx) seems to handle all my concerns fine. The package, not the file format.

Comment: But not because of `tsx` itself, it works because you're telling Node that your own code is ES module code with that package.json `"type"` indicator. With that, Node simply knows to load any CJS dependency in a way that won't break with ESM import syntax. (effectively, even if you didn't want typescript, this is what you need to do if you want to work with ESM in Node, rather than one of the new JS runners like deno or bun)

Comment: You might be right, although I dont really understand. I find it a little odd that it is an option to set type to module at all, if it can load CommonJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `tsx` runner - https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx.
   `tsx foo.ts` to run, `tsx --inspect watch foo.ts` to start watcher with enabled inspector
2. `noEmit` and `esModuleInterop` in tsconfig to avoid any outputs and allow importing cjs
3. `"type": "module"` and `"main": "src /index.ts"` to run tsx .

Comment: The same could work with ts-node, but I'm not sure about its cjs import stability, and making an equivalent of tsx --inspect watch is quite hard

Comment: Thank you, I have actully spent the afternoon looking at the tsx package. Seems like it does a better job then ts-node.